# How to reassemble a wireshark packets to original file sent?

Tags: udp, wireshark

How to reassemble a set of UDP packets to a file sent, in my case it is an image? How to extract data and save as an image? What is some packets was damaged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right-click on one of the UDP packets and select **Follow UDP Stream**
2. In the stream content dialog use **Save As..** to save the raw payload data for the stream
3. You may need to use a binary file editor to remove extra data (eg data sent in the opposite direction or signalling messages) - alternatively, filter these out before step 1 and save in a seperate file
4. If you have missing payload data you will need to repair the image somehow. There are lots of apps available that will do this for standard image formats